# Selenium Webdriver performance versus time

Tags: python, performance, selenium

I'm having issues with selenium webdriver runtime. In fact I'm opening an array with 10 urls and scraping some content.

As the time goes and selenium open the forth url, it gets extremely slow... if I let the task continue, it can't be finished, python aborts the process because of exceeded run time.

Imagine, first url scrape takes 1 minute, the second one 1 - 2 minutes, third 4 minutes, ..., then it breaks.

I need some workaround for this issue, I'm using ipython notebook 2.7.

PS: Do you think opening the url in different tabs could help?

Edit: This is how I create browser:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2,}   
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromeOptions.add_argument("--window-position=0,0")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

This is the task is being run in each url of the array:

```
browser.get(url)

lastHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    newHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
        break
    lastHeight = newHeight

start = 'Por '
end = ' com'

html_source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

cl = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'cl'})
names = [None] * len(cl)
for i in range(len(cl)):
    try: names[i] = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), cl[i].text).group(1)
    except: continue

photosof = list(set(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly Selenium performance is highly dependent of time, it decreases very fast. The only solution I found was to close and reopen the driver.